# Is it possible to modify the data received by a mobile device, using an app on the Mac or PC?

Tags: android, iphone, debugging, proxy, charles-proxy

I used Charles Proxy before, which can modify the data received by a browser, so it is really convenient that we can test our bug fixes without modifying the production server, either for the webpage content or for the AJAX data.

Is it possible to do something similar for a mobile phone app, either for iPhone and Android phones? I can let the Mac (or probably a PC too) act as a Wifi station (access point) and let the mobile phone connect to it, and is there an app that can act like Charles Proxy (perhaps Fiddler?) that can examine and modify data?

Answer (score 1):

@nopole If you are using Charles, I suppose you can use Breakpoint feature to intercept and edit HTTP requests/responses coming from/to your mobile devices. It works for both browsers and mobile devices. Or else you can try using [Proxyman](https://proxyman.io/). It's a native macOS app and quite similar to Charles/ Fiddler. You can read an example of how to use the Breakpoint to manipulate data [here](https://medium.com/@s3798976/use-breakpoint-to-intercept-and-edit-requests-responses-3b4946f020ae). Hope it helps! :)

Comment: is it true that for a webpage, it'd typically go through port 80? For a smartphone app, can it be any port at all (and how can you tell to configure Charles Proxy?)

Comment: Yes I suppose that we would need to configure our devices first so that all the requests/ responses coming from our phone would be captured. If you use Proxyman, you can check out the steps for configurations at https://proxyman.io/blog/2019/06/How-I-use-Proxyman-to-see-HTTP-requests-responses-on-my-iPhone.html. If you use Charles, you can go to Help --> SSL Proxying --> Install Charles Root Certificate on a Mobile Device. There would be a pop-up modal to show you the Server and Port for configuration. Hope it helps!